# Java, detect whether loop stopped because of an unmet condition or break

Tags: java, loops, break

I have a `for` loop that iterates through a `String`, `x`, that if `x` contains a specified `String`. If `x` does contain that `String`, the loop will `break`. It looks something like this:

```
String x = "Hello";
String searchForThis = "e"; // Something to search for
for (int i = 0; i < x.length(); i++) {
  if (x.contains(searchForThis)
    System.out.println("I found it");
    break;
}
```

Now, what I want to do is if the loop ends up completing without finding the `String` to search for, it prints out that the `String` was not found.

I came up with this solution; to check if the loop was iterating for the last time (`i+1 == x.length()`), but it seemed a bit inefficient to me.

```
for (int i = 0; i < x.length(); i++) {
  if (i+1 == x.length() && !x.contains(searchForThis))
    System.out.println("I couldn't find it)";
  else if (x.contains(searchForThis) {
    System.out.println("I found it");
    break;
  }
}
```

I was wondering if there was a way to tell, when a looped stopped, whether it had exited because its condition was no longer `true`, or if it had been stopped because of a `break`; maybe something like this:

```
if (loopStoppedDueToUnmetCondition)
  // Do something
else if (loopStoppedDueToBreakStatement)
  // Do something else
else
  // Do yet another something
```

If there isn't such as thing as this, then I would still greatly appreciate any suggestions on how I could "better" solve my problem mentioned above.
Thanks!

Comment: You need to use curly braces around a multi-line if statement in Java. Indentation is not significant. This code will unconditionally break at the end of the first iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a way to tell if the loop ends up completing without finding the String being searched.

```java
String x = "Hello";
String searchForThis = "e"; // Something to search for
int i = 0;
for (; i < x.length(); i++) {
  if (x.startsWith(searchForThis, i) {
    System.out.println("I found it");
    break;
   }
}
if(i == x.length()) {
   System.out.println("I couldn't find it");
}
```

However, the search condition is all wrong, I changed it to make sense, but all you really need is no loop at all with a single call to "contains".

Answer (score 0):

I would add a boolean and initialize it to false, and change it to true only if the

```
searchForThis
```

is found.

Something like this:

```
String x = "Hello";
        String searchForThis = "i"; // Something to search for
        boolean found = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < x.length(); i++) {
            if (x.contains(searchForThis)) {
                System.out.println("I found it");
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (found) {
            // Do something

        }

        else {
          //Do something else
        }
```